# Как удалить конкретныые данные из таблицы sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram

Пишу телеграм бота на пайтон с помощью pyTelegrambotAPI. Мне нужно удалить из базы данных sqlite3 конкретные значения, подходящие по user_id. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
*def delete_messages(user_id: int):
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('DELETE text FROM user_message WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id, ))
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()*
```

Ошибка: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` удаляет строку из таблицы. Удалить поле невозможно. Можете записать в него `NULL` запросом `UPDATE`.

Comment: `c.execute('UPDATE user_message SET text = null WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id, ))`?

Comment: @gil9red да, именно так.