# Как удалить строку из бд sqlite3 python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Мне нужно удалить все сообщения данного пользователя, что бы удалить сообщения именно этого пользователя я использую user_id. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
 *def delete_messages(user_id: int):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('DELETE text FROM user_message WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id, ))    
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()*
```

Comment: вы уже это раз спросили https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1083044/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-sqlite3-python , зачем еще раз спрашиваете ?

Comment: Мне не дали конкретный ответ

Comment: Если вам помог ответ, пожалуйста отметьте ответ галочкой

Answer (score 2):

```
def delete_messages(user_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('DELETE text FROM user_message WHERE user_id = (?)', (user_id, ))    
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Вроде так должно сработать.

Comment: Да, ещё метод `.format()` помогает. Можете написать `c.execute("""DELETE text FROM user_message WHERE user_id = '{}' """.format(user_id))`